# Как сохранить audio добавленое в div с помощью localStorage?

Tags: javascript, html, localstorage

```js
function f1() {
  var a = document.getElementById("music");
  var e = document.createElement("e");
  var c = a.cloneNode();
  e.appendChild(c);
  var b = document.getElementsByClassName("favourite")[0];
  b.appendChild(e);
  localStorage.setItem("myMus", a);


}
document.getElementsByClassName("favourite")[0].appendChild("e").localStorage.getItem("myMus");
```

```css
.favourite {
  background-color: red;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<audio id="music" controls>
    <source src="horse.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
    <source src="horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
<button onclick="f1()">Add</button>
<div class="favourite"></div>
```

Хочу чтобы при обновлении страницы, аудио добавленный в `div`, сохранялся, но не знаю как это сделать с помощью `localStorage`.

Буду благодарна за помощь.

Comment: вы в localStorage не можете элемент сохранить

Comment: вам нужно там хранить ссылку, на которую ссылается аудио

Comment: Сам эл-т нельзя, но вот его код вполне можно. Хотя в данном случае целесообразней просто ссылку хранить

Comment: Я бы посоветовал, описать суть задуманного, каков должен быть конечный результат,  Из того что в примере, ясно одно, вообще не ясно ничего....

Comment: В localstorage лучше всего сохранять список ссылок на аудио файлы (плейлист) в виде массива, а на странице циклом генерировать плеер для каждой ссылки, которую потом использовать в этом плеере. (если для каждой песни нужен отдельный плеер)

Comment: Да, спасибо, в этом я новичок, по этому не до конца понятно было как с localStorage работать)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Могу предложить сохранение ссылок на аудиофайлы в localStorage и последующее отображение их (даже после обновления страницы) в виде плееров, в даном случае ссылки нужно вводить с помощью prompt:

```html
<div id=favourite></div>
<script>
var mylink = prompt("Введите УРЛ аудиофайла");
var a = localStorage.getItem('tracks');
if(mylink)a += "#&" + mylink;
localStorage.setItem('tracks', a);
var b = a.split("#&");
for(i=1; i < b.length; i ++){
 var audio = new Audio(b[i]);
 audio.controls = true;
 document.getElementById("favourite").appendChild(audio);
 document.getElementById("favourite").innerHTML += "<br />";
}
</script>
```

Comment: Я хотела сделать простенький сайт, добавить на него несколько аудио, а пользователь нажавший на кнопку "добавить аудио" бы мог добавить выбранное аудио в свой плейлист. Но это несерьёзно, а просто для опыта. Нельзя ли это как-то реализовать без ввода prompt ?!)

Comment: Можно. Я уже почти написал код, сегодня чуть позже опубликую.

Comment: Спасибо вам большое, что уделили время, для моего вопроса.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<table border=1>
<tr>
<td id=audiocontayner><center><br />
Общий плейлист<br /><br />
<input type=checkbox />
<audio id="music" controls>
    <source src="1.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
    <source src="1.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio><br />
<input type=checkbox />
<audio id="music" controls>
    <source src="2.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
    <source src="2.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio><br />
<input type=checkbox />
<audio id="music" controls>
    <source src="3.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
    <source src="3.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio><br /><br />
<button onclick="add_audio()"> добавить аудио </button><br /><br />
</center></td><td id=favourite><center>Плейлист пользователя<br /><br />
</center></td>
</tr>
</table>
<script>
var audiocontayner = document.getElementById("audiocontayner");
var favourite = document.getElementById("favourite");
var all_source = audiocontayner.getElementsByTagName("source");
var all_checkbox = audiocontayner.getElementsByTagName("input");
function add_audio(){
 for(i=0;i<all_checkbox.length;i++){
  if(all_checkbox[i].checked){
   var audio = new Audio();
   audio.controls = true;
   var source = document.createElement("source");
   if(b && b.indexOf(all_source[i * 2].src) != -1){
    alert("Такой трек уже есть");
   }else{
    source.src = all_source[i * 2].src;
    source.type = "audio/ogg";
    audio.appendChild(source);
    source = document.createElement("source");
    source.src = all_source[i * 2 + 1].src;
    source.type = "audio/mp3";
    audio.appendChild(source);
    favourite.appendChild(audio);
    favourite.innerHTML += "<br />";
    a += "#&" + all_source[i * 2].src + "#&" + all_source[i * 2 + 1].src;
    localStorage.setItem('tracks', a);
   }
  }
 }
}
var a = localStorage.getItem('tracks');
if(a){
 var b = a.split("#&");
 for(i=1; i < b.length; i += 2){
  var audio = new Audio();
  audio.controls = true;
  var source = document.createElement("source");
  source.src = b[i];
  source.type = "audio/ogg";
  audio.appendChild(source);
  source = document.createElement("source");
  source.src = b[i + 1];
  source.type = "audio/mp3";
  audio.appendChild(source);
  favourite.appendChild(audio);
  favourite.innerHTML += "<br />";
 }
}
</script>
```

Треки в основном списке, которые следует добавить в список пользователя, нужно будет отмечать чекбоксами. Правда, получилось, что проверка на раннее существование в списке пользователя вновь выбираемого трека работает только после обновления страницы. (видимо, уже хочу спать)

Comment: Сказать вам спасибо, будет мало. Я пойду реализовывать написанное. A вам всего хорошего :)

Comment: Спасибо, вам того же :)